# Edit a column of a pandas dataframe based on multiple rows in a different column with adjacent indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset (really just a column of float) lets call 'Units' and a 'Date' as well as an index column I want to replace outliers in. The way I want to do this is to create a percent change column representing the percent change from the last day to the current day of 'Units' and filter out any values in 'Units' where the absolute value of the percent change for that day and for the next day is greater than lets say 8 and those two values are of opposite sign.(to remove any days which are a big spike and then a return to the normal pattern) I want to impute the average of 'Units' for the two days surrounding that day into the day which is an outlier. So for something like:

```
Date  || Units  ||    Percent_Change

12/31 || 800    ||    -

01/01 || 920    ||    ~+15

01/02 || 1120   ||    ~+22

01/03 || 1130   ||    ~+1

01/04 || 1129   ||    ~-0.1

01/05 || 1145   ||    ~+1.8

01/06 || 900    ||    ~-12

01/07 || 1155   ||    ~+23

01/08 || 1199   ||    ~+3

01/09 || 1400   ||    ~+14

01/10 || 1385   ||    ~-2
```

I would impute 1150 on 01/06

I originally tried looping through the dataframe, but I dont really want to do it that way. I have looked into documentation for map and filter but Im unsure how I would access the index of the row I am working on for a lambda function or something like that as well as how to involve more conditional edits to that.

```
#Heres some code that I think would work or at least conceptually makes sense to me, but id like to avoid looping through

for row in df.itertuples():
    if(row.Index <= 1):
        continue
    if(abs(row.percent_change) > 8 and abs(df[row.Index-1]['percent_change']) > 8 and row.percent_change * df[row.Index-1]['percent_change'] < 0):
        df[row.Index-1]['Units'] = (df[row.Index]['Units']+df[row.Index-2]['Units'])/2
```

Can anyone help?

(I want a more pandas way of doing this so it will be fast)

Comment: check out shift: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
date = ['12/31','01/01','01/02','01/03','01/04','01/05','01/06','01/07','01/08','01/09','01/10']
units = [800,920,1120,1130,1129,1145,900,1155,1199,1400,1385]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(date, units)), columns=['date', 'units'])

df["percent_change"] = (df['units'] - df['units'].shift(1))/df['units'].shift(1)
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys'))
    date      units    percent_change
--  ------  -------  ----------------
 0  12/31       800     nan
 1  01/01       920       0.15
 2  01/02      1120       0.217391
 3  01/03      1130       0.00892857
 4  01/04      1129      -0.000884956
 5  01/05      1145       0.0141718
 6  01/06       900      -0.213974
 7  01/07      1155       0.283333
 8  01/08      1199       0.0380952
 9  01/09      1400       0.16764
10  01/10      1385      -0.0107143
```

EDIT FOR IMPUTED CALCULATION

After viewing [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), I would create another column for the imputed units using np.where. You can edit for whatever condition you want, I just checked for negative percentage on the raw calculation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate

date = ['12/31', '01/01', '01/02', '01/03', '01/04', '01/05', '01/06', '01/07', '01/08', '01/09', '01/10']
units = [800, 920, 1120, 1130, 1129, 1145, 900, 1155, 1199, 1400, 1385]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(date, units)), columns=['date', 'units'])

df['calculation_row'] = df['units']
df["raw_percent_change"] = (df['units'] - df['units'].shift(1)) / df['units'].shift(1)

df = df.assign(
    imputed_units=np.where(
        (df['raw_percent_change'] < 0) &
        (df['raw_percent_change'] != np.NaN) ,

        (df['units'].shift(-1) + df['units'].shift(1)) / 2,
        df['units'])
)

df["imputed_percent_change"] = (df['imputed_units'] - df['imputed_units'].shift(1)) / df['imputed_units'].shift(1)


print(tabulate(df, headers='keys'))
    date      units    calculation_row    raw_percent_change    imputed_units    imputed_percent_change
--  ------  -------  -----------------  --------------------  ---------------  ------------------------
 0  12/31       800                800         nan                      800                nan
 1  01/01       920                920           0.15                   920                  0.15
 2  01/02      1120               1120           0.217391              1120                  0.217391
 3  01/03      1130               1130           0.00892857            1130                  0.00892857
 4  01/04      1129               1129          -0.000884956           1137.5                0.00663717
 5  01/05      1145               1145           0.0141718             1145                  0.00659341
 6  01/06       900                900          -0.213974              1150                  0.00436681
 7  01/07      1155               1155           0.283333              1155                  0.00434783
 8  01/08      1199               1199           0.0380952             1199                  0.0380952
 9  01/09      1400               1400           0.16764               1400                  0.16764
10  01/10      1385               1385          -0.0107143              nan                nan
```

Comment: this answer is good for calculating the percent_change but my problem is imputing values for the outliers

Comment: @watersbruce1999 please see my edits for that imputation calculation for the units you want to use in the percent change calculation